# Example: How would a Child class access Canvas within Parent?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Can someone give me an example of how a child class would access the canvas of the parent class to draw something, i.e a bitmap:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    Bitmap bitmap_explosion = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),com.forwardapps.tanks.R.drawable.explosion, options);
```

context.drawBitmap(bitmap_explosion, x, y, null);

This is what I have in the child, in the parent I've got:

```
Explosion xplode = new Explosion(this._context, 50, 50);
```

I've been looking around for a few hours now, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't draw Bitmaps randomly in code. You would need to submit your object to some type of rendering view. So for example you might have:

```
public class Scene extends View{
  private List<Explosions> explosions = new ArrayList<Explosions>();
  @Override
  public void onDraw(){
     //obviously i have a concurrency issue here.. meh
     for (Explosions e:explosions){
     /// draw your explosions here

     }

  }

  public void addExplosion(Explosions x){
       explosions.add(x)
  }
}
```

When you call add explosions, dont forget to call `postInvalidate` to ask the view to redraw it's self.

But to answer your question most directly, you want your child class to implement `Drawable` and then pass the canvas to the child classes `onDraw()` method from the parent classes `onDraw` method.